# Pivot xml column label and java

Tags: java, oracle, pivot, sqlxml

i have a stored procedure in my database which contains a pivot statement.

```
create or replace procedure example1(var1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
is
DATE_FROM date;
DATE_TO date;
begin
  DATE_TO := sysdate;
  DATE_FROM := sysdate -10;
  open var1 for
    select *
    from
    ( select m as MONTHS, s as SERIES, SUM(t) as N
      from tablename
      WHERE dateletter BETWEEN date_from AND date_to
      group by m, s
      ORDER BY m
    )
   PIVOT XML (SUM(N) as TOTALSUM for SERIES in (select distinct s from tablename where dateletter between date_from and date_to group by s));
END example1;
```

This works fine and this displays something like this

```
Month SERIES_XML

  2   oracle.jdbc.driver.ORACLESQLXML@d77ww5
```

Now in my java class

```
CallableStatement acs1;
acs1 = generalcon.con.prepareCall(getCursor);
acs1.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
acs1.executeQuery();
ars1 = (ResultSet) acs1.getObject(1);
while(ars1.next())
{
  String ser = ars1.getString(2);
  xmlst      = xmlst + ser;

}
```

However, `ars1.getString(2)` is returning a null value, where 1 is the ColumnIndex
I tried with `ars1.getString('SERIES_XML')` but the same result.

Can you help me out to get the correct column name and corresponding value please

Comment: Not strong in this area, but not sure whether your `getCursor` is correct (it should be a string that evaluates to something like `begin example1(?); end;`) ... does this help: http://www.enterprisedt.com/publications/oracle/result_set.html

Comment: @JeffreyKemp the 'getCursor' is good

Comment: maybe should you be calling `acs1.execute` instead of `executeQuery`?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp it think it will be same as it will return a resultset. From the resultset, i must get the column! so its not worth

Comment: ah, I see you're an expert :) Personally, being inexperienced, I would have tried using execute(), then just call acs1.getString(1) to get the out parameter; but then, that's just me :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp yep, its ze same thing

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have this problem, recently I have the same thing and this helps me to get all the columns in the ResultSet:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

// The column count starts from 1
for (int j = 1; j <= columnCount; j++) {
    System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(j) + " - " + rsmd.getColumnType(j) + " - " + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(j));
}
```

Bye!